# dotnet build fails, but works when using MSBuild from Mono

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, mono, .net-core

I'm having a asp.net core project running on asp.net core 2.0. The project was created with asp.net core 1.0.

When running `dotnet build` I get errors like:

```
_Layout.sv.resx : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. Length cannot be less than zero.
```

It's the same for all resx files.

How ever, if I run thru Rider Mac or Visual Studio Mac using MSBuild 15 from Mono framework it works just fine.

But MSBuild from dotnet 2.0 does not work.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I know that this is a really stupid question, but do the resx files have any content in them? Also, is it possibly related to the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2073

Comment: Not that easy I'm afraid. It works fine on Windows too, so this is probably something in the dotnet cli on OSX.